# 1958 Lang's book on algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ho.history-overview

Is the famous 1958 Lang's book "introduction to algebraic geometry" a reasonable account of the pre-Grothendieck era of algebraic geometry ?

Or, in the contrary, does this book present a quite narrow view on that ?

If so, which important subjects of algebraic geometry of that time are left aside ?

Is the presentation of field theory based on places in that book worth reading, or is it obsolete nowadays ? Are there field theory results that cannot be proven without the notion of places, or is it just a convenient tool that could be avoided ?

Comment: Nobody to answer my questions ?...